# Replacing iPhone's logic-board to unlock its SIM card

Tags: iphone, unlock

I have an iPhone 5c locked under AT&T, and I was trying to unlock it in many ways but nothing worked. I'm wondering if I replace its logic board, would it get unlocked or not?!

Answer (score 1):

To unlock your phone, you should contact AT&T to do so. It is free and allowed under their ToS, as long as you are eligible.

Please see [https://www.att.com/deviceunlock/](https://www.att.com/deviceunlock/#/) for more information.

If you actually wanted to replace the logic board, you would have to do so from a phone designed to work on the AT&T network and it itself is already unlocked - which would be nearly impossible to determine unless you actually did the swap and/or were provided IMEI information on the device prior to purchase. Considering the complexity of the repair, you'd probably be better off just buying an unlocked whole phone off of Craigslist, etc. due to time and cost involved, as well as risk to the device.